# Receiving error C4700 and unable to finish driver program

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

struct Student {
    char*      name;
    float      gpa;
};

Student * createStudent( char name[], float gpa) {

    Student * studentPtr;

    studentPtr = new Student;

    studentPtr->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    studentPtr->name = name;
    studentPtr->gpa = gpa;

    // Return the pointer
    return studentPtr;
}

bool destroyStudent(Student*& aStudent) {
    if (aStudent) { //check whether this pointer is already null.
        free(aStudent->name);
        delete aStudent; 
        aStudent = nullptr;
        return true;
    }
    return false; //aStudent is already null
}


int main() {
    Student * student1 = createStudent(student1->name, student1->gpa); //error is here
    cout << "Enter Student's name: " << endl;
    cin >> student1->name;
    cout << "Enter GPA: " << endl;
    cin >> student1->gpa;
    cout << student1->name << " and " << student1->gpa << endl;
    destroyStudent(student1);
    if (student1) {
        cout << "Pointer is NOT null!!!" << endl;
        student1 = nullptr;
    }

    if (!student1) {
        cout << "The pointer is null now." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to finish a driver program where I can test my functions, but I have been unsuccessful. With every change I make, it just adds more error messages. This was the closest I could get, with only one error that I could not resolve.

Error message:

> Error 1   error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'student1' used

Any help is highly appreciated. I already searched this error on here, and could not resolve myself :(

Comment: Did you try to google your error? I believe the first link will point to MSDN with the explanation and an example.

Comment: you try to create object using this object fields...

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do here:

```
Student * student1 = createStudent(student1->name, student1->gpa);
```

This is **totally wrong!** You try to create a `Student` object with the fields of an object you try to create - don't you see logical error here?

The one of correct usages is:

```
Student * student1 = createStudent("Smith", 4.0f);
```

You **can't** use objects which are not created yet and you do this which causes a error.